# Automatically make QMdiSubWindow the smallest size possible

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmdiarea

I'm trying to get an QMdiSubWindow to become the smallest size possible after generating the widgets.

Base .ui looks like this:
[image]

I then add a raster of widgets (checkboxes and lineedits) in the *selected* layout.
The window then renders quire relax with large line widgets. I can manually shrink the window to become almost half of what was initially shown.

How can I shrink the window automatically to the minimum sizes of the containing widgets?

I've tried playing with the sizepolicy, they either fix the widgets size, or make it larger...
The only thing that seems to be correct is the minimumSizeHint(), but there seems to be no way to apply that to a QMdiSubWindow? The resize() function does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the QMdiSubWindow size from within the widget it renders if you create the mdi windows like this:

```
QMdiSubWindow *subWindow = new QMdiSubWindow();
MyWidget *widget = new MyWidget(this);
subWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
subWindow->setParent(ui->mdiArea);
subWindow->setWidget(widget);
subWindow->show();
```

When you add `subWindow->resize(subWindow->minimumSizeHint());` it works fine!